# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pptx'

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, anaconda, python-pptx

I am using windows and have anaconda installed. I pip installed python-pptx. and I can see it at the same location where my numpy, pandas, seaborn and other libraries are. All other libraries are working in jupyter notebook except this. This the error i get when i type from pptx import Presentation

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pptx'[image]

Comment: I have numpy, pandas and seaborn in site-packages. I am able to use all of them except pptx.

Comment: could I know why did the xyz person downvote? There isn't anything existing on the internet helping me. I have done my research. The one who downvoted your opinion is welcomed.

Comment: Pretty sure this is primarily an anaconda issue, like it maintains its own python environment and pip doesn't install there usually. I would try using `conda` to install `python-pptx` or perhaps install `pip` into the conda environment, but I don't use anaconda so I'm just guessing there. But if you search on "anaconda not finding pip installed package" you'll find it's a common problem and that might give you some direction.